# SubSelect Top 1 OR Left Join

Tags: sql-server

I have a Select with sub selects using Top 1 and where clause.

I tried to optimize the select by doing a Left Join of the sub selects but the query time took longer. Is subselect better in this case? I couldnt post my whole select because it is too long and confidential but I will try to recreate the important part below:

Sub Select

```
SELECT 
(select top 1 colId FROM table1 WHERE col1 = b.Id and col2 = 3 Order by 1) Id3,
(select top 1 colId FROM table1 WHERE col1 = b.Id and col2 = 5 Order by 1) Id5,
(select top 1 colId FROM table1 WHERE col1 = b.Id and col2 = 7 Order by 1) Id7
FROM    table2 b
```

Trying it w/ Left Join

```
SELECT 
    t1.colid id3,
    t2.colid id5,
    t3.colid id7
FROM    table2 b
LEFT JOIN (
        select colId, col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 3
    ) t1 ON t1.col1 = b.Id 
LEFT JOIN (
        select colId, col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 5
    ) t2 ON t1.col1 = b.Id 
LEFT JOIN (
        select colId, col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 7
    ) t3 ON t1.col1 = b.Id
```

Is there a better way to do this? and why is it the Left join takes longer query time?

Comment: `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` clause is meaningless. Also: your two queries are not equivalent.

Comment: im sorry you are correct, i will edit. I forgot to put the order by

Comment: I think you need an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp doesnt INNER JOIN filter my rows if it doesnt exist? While the sub select TOP 1/ Left Join can return a NULL value for a row?

Comment: You should drop the habit of ordering by ordinal position. Not only is it super confusing it is also deprecated. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/deprecated-t-sql-features Think about what happens when the columns change, if you don't also change the order by you can get incorrect results.

Comment: @SeanLange that is noted, in our current select it is not by ordinal position. It is by the column name. Thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  a.colId,
            rn = ROWN_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.col2 ORDER BY a.col1)
    FROM      table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.col1 = b.id
    WHERE   a.col2 IN (3,5,7)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will give you the first row for each `col2` value and you can restrict the values you want to 3,5,7.

Comment: How do I include this in my SP Select?